# awk variables to bash

Tags: bash, file, awk, syntax-error

I have a file with 5 columns and want to use it like variables in bash. When I wanna read just one variable, for example read  from `file.dat` the variable in column 3, I use

```
var=$(awk 'print($3)' file.dat)
```

I want to read the last three columns and save it into an array or multiple variables, It that possible? Maybe there is an easier way

Comment: Please add sample input (no descriptions, no images, no links) and your desired output for that sample input to your question (no comment).

Comment: Are you planning to write a script so you can use `array=($(script -c 3,4,5 file.dat))` to assign to an array, or will you write the `awk` out by hand each time `array=($(awk '{ print $3, $4, $5 }' file.dat))` or what?  Saving into multiple variables with a single invocation of `awk` is harder; you'd end up doing something similar to `eval`, which is dangerous (a security risk) but doable.

Comment: `awk 'print($3)' file.dat` I doubt that if you got the correct result by this awk line.

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/q/29158506/2088135

Comment: At each point in your question change "variable" and "array" to "awk variable" or "shell variable" and "awk array" or "shell array" to clarify which things you're trying to reference/populate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like this question: [setting multiple variables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8579294/bash-setting-multiple-variables-in-a-single-pipeline-stage).
In your case, you can try something like:

```
awk '{ print($1 " " $2 " " $3 " " $4 " " $5); }' file.dat | { read a b c d e; echo $a $b $c $d $e; }
```

Or if you need to loop over lines from your file.dat:

```
awk '{ print( $1 " " $2 " " $3 " " $4 " " $5); }' file.dat | \
{ while read a b c d e; do echo $a $b $c $d $e; done; }
```